# Spring Web Flow: setting request parameter for JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, mocking, junit4, spring-webflow-2

### Introduction

I have a Java/Tomcat/Spring 2.5/Spring Webflow 2.0.9 web application. To test some of the pages I have created JUnit tests, which set values to the form objects and mimic the requests coming from the browser. The JUnit test class looks something like this:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/WebTests-context.xml", "classpath:/messageSourceConfig.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class InitechValidatorTests {

    protected MockHttpSession session;
    protected MockHttpServletRequest request;

    //test methods omitted

    protected void startSession() {
        session = new MockHttpSession();
    }

    protected void endSession() {
        session.clearAttributes();
        session = null;
    }

    protected void startRequest() {
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.setSession(session);
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

        MockRequestContext mrc = new MockRequestContext();
        org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder.setRequestContext(mrc);

        MessageContext messageContext = org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext()
                .getMessageContext();
        this.validationContext.setMessageContext(messageContext);
    }

    protected void endRequest() {
        ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).requestCompleted();
        RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
        request = null;

        org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder.setRequestContext(null);
    }
}
```

For each test method I call the startRequest and endRequest methods (startSession is called before the first test method and endSession after the last test method). Without this construct I couldn't use e.g. RequestContextHolder in the code I'm testing.

### The problem

In the class to test I read the contents of a request parameter from the web flow like this:

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
ExternalContext externalContext = requestContext.getExternalContext();
String printPressed = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("printPressed");
```

I would need to set the "printPressed" request parameter in my JUnit test method like this:

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext requestContext = org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder
                    .getRequestContext();
ExternalContext externalContext = requestContext.getExternalContext();
Map requestParamMap = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().asMap();
requestParamMap.put("printPressed", "true");
```

That is, however impossible because the map is immutable and results in an UnsupportedOperationException.

The question is: how to set a request parameter to the requestParameterMap in the class [org.springframework.webflow.context.ExternalContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/context/ExternalContext.html)? The parameter map returned by [getRequestParameterMap](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29) is immutable, so I cannot add the parameter there. I noticed that there is e.g. an object [MockParameterMap](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/test/MockParameterMap.html), which sounds promising: *"A extension of parameter map that allows for mutation of parameters. Useful as a stub for testing."*

**How can I inject the MockParameterMap to the ExternalContext in the test class? Or is there some other way to set the request parameters for unit testing?**

Answer (score 4):

Solved the problem by modifying the startRequest method so that I set the [MockParameterMap](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/test/MockParameterMap.html) to a new [MockExternalContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html) object, which is set to the [MockRequestContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/test/MockRequestContext.html) followingly:

```
MockParameterMap mpp = new MockParameterMap();
MockExternalContext mec = new MockExternalContext(mpp);
mrc.setExternalContext(mec);
```

Then in the JUnit test method I can set the parameter followingly:

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext requestContext = org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder
                    .getRequestContext();
ExternalContext externalContext = requestContext.getExternalContext();
MockParameterMap requestParameterMap = (MockParameterMap) externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
requestParameterMap.put("printPressed", "true");
```